# History of Moment Generating Functions

Tags: soft-question, math-history, moment-generating-functions

I am beginning to appreciate how important [Moment Generating Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) (MGFs) are regarding various common probability distributions and the ways their expectations/variances are calculated.

My open-ended question is: What is the history of MGFs? Who was first to develop them/introduce notation/generalize properties of MGFs?

**Please don't close this question or put it on hold because it is primarily opinion-based**; I just haven't been able to find any information about the history of MGFs and I'm very curious about their origin/development.

Comment: I had a look in the index of Stigler and there was nothing obvious. Would be a good one for the http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/area-51-proposal-history-of-mathematics-and-science if it gets off the ground.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question!  By searching on JSTOR, the oldest paper I found where the term moment generating function is used (in some statistical context) is the following paper:
Rider, Paul R. “A Survey of the Theory of Small Samples.” Annals of Mathematics, vol. 31, no. 4, 1930, pp. 577–628. Second Series, www.jstor.org/stable/1968155.
which actually looks somewhat modern! 
As the moment generating function is related to the Laplace transform, some answers here: [What kind of book would show where the inspiration for the Laplace transform came from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172567/what-kind-of-book-would-show-where-the-inspiration-for-the-laplace-transform-cam/172587#172587)  might be helpful

(I will come back to this question continuing the search for early papers)