# Soft question - Laplace transformation historical development

Tags: soft-question, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

**This is a soft question**

I'm looking for a book that explains in detail at least some of this points regarding Laplace transform:

- Motivations that led to the development of the transform.
- Detailed proof of the theorem.
- Why it can be used to transform a function from contínuos time to discrete time and back.
- Some physical intuition regarding the transform.

I know Laplace transformation is special case of Fourier transformation so any recommendation about the later will be appreciated.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172567/what-kind-of-book-would-show-where-the-inspiration-for-the-laplace-transform-cam) is closely related. Could be a duplicate, even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [The development of the Laplace transform, 1737–1937](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01395660)
- [The development of the Laplace Transform, 1737–1937 II. Poincaré to Doetsch, 1880–1937](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00418754)
- [The ascendancy of the Laplace transform and how it came about](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00377050)