# What is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_nz^n|^2=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(ze^{it})|^2dt$ for?

Tags: power-series, examples-counterexamples

Let $f : \mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be an analytic function : $f(z)= \sum a_n z^n$

It holds that

$$a_n z^n= \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(ze^{it})e^{-int}dt$$

and 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_nz^n|^2=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(ze^{it})|^2dt$$

I wonder what the last formula is useful for (the first gives the coefficients in the power series of $f$ knowing only $f$). Can you give some examples where this identity proves useful ?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/connection-between-fourier-transform-and-taylor-series/7312#7312) is related, in case you didn't already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful for polynomial..like:

- Let $f(z)=\sum_{n= 0}^{+\infty}a_n z^n$, the radius of convergence $R\ge 1$.

$\forall n,\quad a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ is bounded on the open unit disk.

Then one can prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

- (Oral X) Let $f(z)=z^{n}+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_{0}$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq1$.

If $\lvert f(z)\rvert\le 1$, for all $\lvert z\rvert=1$, then one can show that $f=z^n$.

- I forgot this famous theorem : Due to Liouville

The only developable functions in power series and bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ are 
constant functions.

Comment: Pour l'exo de l'X, on peut prendre $f$ non unitaire. D'autre part on peut montrer que les polynômes de $C[X]$ de degré $n$ qui envoient le cercle unité dans lui-même sont les $\alpha X^n$ où $|\alpha|=1$.

Comment: @GabrielR. (mal lu) Oui tout à fait. L'exo vient de l'ODP

Comment: c'est quoi l'ODP ?

Comment: @GabrielR. L'Officiel de la taupe

Comment: "qui n'a rien d'officiel!" d'après mon prof de spé(qui écrit pour la RMS)...

Answer (score 0):

By considering $a_0$ and $f(z)=\underbrace{ \exp( \exp(... \exp(}_{n-1}z)))$, we have the very nice
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\underbrace{\exp(\exp(...\exp(}_{n}it)))dt=2\pi\underbrace{ \exp( \exp(... \exp(}_{n-2}1))).$$