# Relation between representation of a number in an integer base and Fourier series representation of a periodic signal

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am not a Mathematician - am just a software developer though I did some "Math" back in the day as part of my undergrad studies millions of years ago.

Recently I had to revisit Fourier analysis of signals for an application I am working on, and it struck me that if you squinted at it just right, it had some similarity to the representations of numbers in an integer base as given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Basis_Representation_Theorem)  (with the trigonometric or complex exponential functions being replaced by powers of the base integer, e.g.,  $123 = 1 \times 10^2 + 2 \times 10^1 + 3 \times 10^0$). I understand that the powers of integers are not orthogonal to each other, but otherwise, I was wondering if there is any overarching "theory" that includes these two as special cases? Does, for e.g., Harmonic analysis cover representation of integers by powers of integer bases?

Edit: the same I suppose could be said for the Taylor series expansion of functions as well, with the harmonic exponential or trigonometric functions being replaced by powers of variables.

Comment: The Taylor series - Fourier transform relation is explained here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/connection-between-fourier-transform-and-taylor-series , as I later found out. The basis representation question still remains.

Comment: In fact, power series (Taylor series, for example) are very closely related to Fourier series. The $Z$-transform makes the connections more explicit.

Comment: I don't know about basis representations of numbers, though. If you try and frame it in the linear algebraic sense of a "basis", then a lot of things don't quite fit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your reply. I have attempted to make the question clearer. By "basis representation", I meant representation of a number in a given base. E.g., $123 = 1 \times 10^2 + 2 \times 10^1 + 3 \times 10^0$

Comment: I understand, but the statement stands