# How does doing a Fourier Transform affect a functions' power series representation?

Tags: analysis, soft-question, fourier-analysis, power-series

Assume I have some function $t\to f(t)$ that is well behaved enough to have a Fourier Transform $w\to \mathcal F\{f(t)\}(w)$ as well as a power series expansion $$p(t) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^+} c_kt^k$$ that converges everywhere. Furthermore assume that the Fourier Transform also has such a power series expansion.
$$p_F(w) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^+} d_kw^k$$

Can I derive some relationship between $\{c_k\}$ and $\{d_k\}$?

Comment: Possibly useful: [(Question 7301)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/connection-between-fourier-transform-and-taylor-series).

Comment: No it's not the same. This regards the monomial power series in the frequency variable not the trigonometric power series which is the transform itself.